# Options error: Parameter ca_file can only be specified in TLS-mode

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, openvpn, ssl

Im currently trying to setup an OpenVPN Client on my Raspberry Pi.
I keep on getting some error messages related to TLS.

The syslog gives me this:

```
Nov 23 08:34:56 raspberrypi ovpn-ersterclient[1370]: disabling NCP mode (-- 
ncp-disable) because not in P2MP client or server mode
Nov 23 08:34:56 raspberrypi ovpn-ersterclient[1370]: Options error: 
Parameter ca_file can only be specified in TLS-mode, i.e. where --tls-server 
or --tls-client is also specified.
Nov 23 08:34:56 raspberrypi ovpn-ersterclient[1370]: Use --help for more 
information.
Nov 23 08:34:56 raspberrypi systemd[1]: openvpn@ersterclient.service: 
Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 23 08:34:56 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection 
to ersterclient.
Nov 23 08:34:56 raspberrypi systemd[1]: openvpn@ersterclient.service: Unit 
entered failed state.
Nov 23 08:34:56 raspberrypi systemd[1]: openvpn@ersterclient.service: Failed 
with result 'exit-code'.
```

And my .conf looks like this:

```
dev tun
proto udp
remote IP 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA1
comp-lzo
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
CERT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
CERT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
CERT
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [OpenVPN Reference Manual](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-0/):

> OpenVPN supports conventional encryption using a pre-shared secret key
>   (Static Key mode) or public key security (SSL/TLS mode) using client &
>   server certificates. OpenVPN also supports non-encrypted TCP/UDP
>   tunnels.

To operate in TLS mode you need to add `tls-server` to the server config and `tls-client` to the client config along with the CA certificate, server certificate and private key which you already have.

Alternatively, to work in pre-shared key mode you'll need to remove all references to certificates and private keys from the config files and ensure you're using the `secret` option pointing to a shared key.

Presumably (although I've not tried it), if you remove both you'll end up with the non-encrypted TCP/UDP tunnel it mentions, which won't provide any security.